# Password less sudo in script

Tags: cron, scripting, sudo

I have **passwordless access** to a server. My user account has added in **sudoers** file for **NOPASSWD** usage for some services/daemons in /etc/init.d/.

I want to write a **script** to start or stop a daemon according to some test results. I had set a cron to run this script at a specific time. But it returns error "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified".

I can use the " sudo /etc/init.d/service name start/stop without password in terminal.I do not have root password.

I have double checked /etc/sudoers file. There is no  "requiretty". I am using Ubuntu-10.04 , 2.6.32-24-generic.

Following are the active lines in sudoers:

```
Defaults        env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
bijo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: are you calling the script on the server or from your remote machine?

Answer (score 7):

If you are running the script as the same user as the one that has no password access then it should work correctly, i would make sure that the script is running as the correct user, I would also test the script by manually calling it as the right user.

You may also need to check that the following line doesn't exist in the sudoers file or that you have a further line which states your user doesn't require a TTY

```
Defaults requiretty
```

if that line is present you can either comment it out (not a good idea) its probably better to add the following in

```
Defaults:<USERNAME> !requiretty
```

where USERNAME is your user

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sudoers file does not contain Defaults requiretty. I am using cron to run the script. If run the script manually, it works fine...

Comment: One more similar question: I have sudoers entry 

    bijo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2

and set a cron as 

    */2 * * * * sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start >>testingcrn.out 2>&1

Want to start/stop apache **using cron**.

It return **error** "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" in the output file testingcrn.out.

Any Idea??

Comment: Are you sure about the requiretty line not being present ? I think its default on all major distros.

Comment: The only possibility, if it's not `requiretty`, is that your defined sudo line is not getting hit when it's called by `cron` due to a different `PATH`.  Quick way to test, though; just set `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` for the user running the crontab and see if the error still happens.  If it does, your issue is `requiretty`; if it doesn't, your issue is probably `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `ssh -t`

Comment: only if he is doing the command remotely from another server right?

Comment: oops, i assumed its from a remote server, some how can't down vote my own answer

Comment: he didnt specify what way he is triggering so it may still be valid

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where I can use it? I do not have root password. Plz help......

Comment: Bijo are you calling the script via cron on the server itself or from your local machine?

Comment: Cron and script are in the server

Comment: One more similar question: I have sudoers entry 

    bijo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2

and set a cron as 

    */2 * * * * sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start >>testingcrn.out 2>&1

Want to start/stop apache **using cron**.

It return **error** "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" in the output file testingcrn.out.

Any Idea??

Answer (score 1):

That complaint message comes from part of the code which is asking for the password, so is complaining because without a tty, it can't disable echo.  You can prove to yourself that you're in this code-path by setting the `visiblepw` option in sudoers, which will avoid that warning and let you see the password prompt.

So ultimately, something is wrong with the `NOPASSWD:` control.

When multiple rules in `sudoers` match, the **last** match is used, not the most specific.  So user `bijo` is in %sudo or %admin; thus the `NOPASSWD:` control is not applied.

Did your testing at the command-line happen before you logged out/in after adding yourself to one of those groups?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Defaults !requiretty` line to the bottom of the file. This will explicitly turn off requiretty for everything.